# Решение линейного уравнения с помощью LU разложения

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть сомнения, что правильно перенес выделенные формулы из учебника в с++
Где `L[n][n]` и `U[n][n]` ранее посчитанные

```
double y[n];    //Находим y[n] по формуле (2.11)
sum = 0;  
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int k = 0; k < n-1 ; k++) {
        sum += L[i][k] * y[k];
        y[i] = B[i] - sum;
    }

cout << endl << "y[n] = " << endl;      //Выводим y[n]
funcScrean(y,n);

double x[n];    //Находим x[n] по формуле (2.13)
sum = 0;
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    for (int k = i  ; k < n ; k++) {
        sum += U[i][k] * x[k];
        x[i] = (y[i] - sum)/(U[i][i]);
    }
```

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем? Или это тест на телепатические способности?

Comment: Прошу прощения, просто не сразу разобрался. Добавил немного описания сверху

Comment: @ДенисД - Ничего, ничего. Тут все любят сложные вопросы.

Comment: А у меня вот нет сомнений, что вы где-то ошиблись. Но это не отменяет нормальной формулировки вопроса: что не сходится, как не сходится, что должно получаться, что получается и так далее. Для начала советую попробовать поработать с отладчиком.

Comment: @Igor, сложные вопросы это хорошо. А вот просьбы поработать отладчиком (или телепатом) -- это, как минимум, не вежливо

Comment: @DmitriySimushev - Я согласен, конечно. Зато как круто, если угадаешь!

Comment: @ДенисД, рекомендую ознакомиться с правилами о том, [на какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Человек написал какой-то код, даже выложил формулы, а вы тут чем-то недовольны и пытаетесь закрыть :(

Comment: LEQADA Попробовал упростить свой вопрос, как написано в справке

Comment: @ДенисД: А почему вы не пользуетесь отладчиком? Ответ «не умею» не принимается.

Comment: VladD Попробую завтра тогда разобраться через отладчик, за одно и разберусь что это

Answer (score 2):

Например, формула 2.11 гораздо больше похожа на

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    sum = 0;  
    for (int k = 0; k < i ; k++) {
        sum += L[i][k] * y[k];
    }
    y[i] = B[i] - sum;
}
```

чем на Ваше

```
sum = 0;  
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int k = 0; k < n-1 ; k++) {
        sum += L[i][k] * y[k];
        y[i] = B[i] - sum;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: @Igor, да вы-таки телепат. Или отладчик))

Comment: Пока, вроде, не разобрался, но вроде норм работает, А вторая, если не сложно

Comment: @ДенисД - имейте совесть - найдите отличия между моим и Вашим вариантами, и Вам станет ясно, что изменить в коде для второй формулы.

Comment: Все, большое спасибо, все работает, все сходится